# Java: I'm using File and made a class FileHelper and calling it with JSP in a webpage... help?

Tags: java

```
FileHelper fileList = new FileHelper();
ArrayList<String> files = fileList.getFiles("C://temp", 3);
```

This is what I have for the path (the 3 is how many folders deep I want it to go). It works exactcly how I want it to when its just running from localhost. However, when I upload it to the web, I can't have the C drive, so what would I put there instead?

I've gotten this error on everything Ive tried:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /content/reports.jsp at line 23

21: <%

22: FileHelper2 fileList = new FileHelper2();

23: ArrayList<String> files = fileList.getFiles("C://", 3);
```

Comment: This seems to be a simple issue. Where did you upload your application to? Is that a Windows server or another o/s ?

Comment: OK, Please post additional exception - such as exception stack trace form the application server log - if any. That will help people to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

If your utility method is just loading files off the file system, you will need to provide a full path to a file on the system on which your app is hosted.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to smp7d's answer, I'd add that you can either have the file be relative to your app, and retrieve the path with `ServletContext.getRealPath(path)`, or have an absolute path that's reasonable for your environment, or have something relative to your app's classpath and serve it as a resource (rather than file-system file).

An absolute path value could be provided by a `-D` server startup parameter (ew), a servlet `init-param` (better), a framework-specific parameter, loaded from a classpath property resource, etc.

Comment: Thats a way better approach to load files in webapps rather than hardcoding filepath.